# Multiple components in single parent page in salesforce

Tags: visualforce-component, component

I have created a salesforce component XYZ & used 2 component's in a single page. There is an "Assign" button in the component which saves data. But when I click on the Assign button of component1 then it calls the second components method.

Further to my finding I found my assign button call saveContact() javascript & then it calls actionFunction afsaveContact(). When I click on the assign button it calls saveContact() javascript of component2 as both the components are in a single page. In my single page when I checked from the browser developer tool I found 2 saveContact() methods which actually caused the problem. So if a user clicks on the first component it calls saveContact() on the second component. What I should do to avoid this problem. I checked if the component had any attribute to avoid this problem but no luck.

[image]

```
function saveContact(){
        afsaveContact();
     }

<apex:actionFunction name="afsaveContact" action="{!saveContact}" rerender="pbMultiContactId" status="splashStatus"></apex:actionFunction>
```

This is how I called components from my single page.

```
 <div class="avTableRow">
                                    <apex:panelGroup id="customerContactDetail" style="width:30%;vertical-align: top;" styleclass="avTableColumnWithoutBorder">
                                        <c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents showControl="true" id="MulticustomerContactDetailId" companyType="Program" assessmentObjMulitiContact="{!newAssessment}" >
                                        </c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents>
                                    </apex:panelGroup>

                                    <apex:panelGroup id="vendorContactDetail" style="width:30%;vertical-align: top;" styleclass="avTableColumnWithoutBorder">
                                        <c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents showControl="true" id="MultivendorContactDetailId" companyType="Vendor" assessmentObjMulitiContact="{!newAssessment}" >
                                        </c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents>
                                    </apex:panelGroup>

                                    <apex:panelGroup id="factoryContactDetail"  style="width:30%;vertical-align: top;" styleclass="avTableColumnWithoutBorder">
                                        <c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents showControl="true" id="MultifactoryContactDetailId" companyType="Factory" assessmentObjMulitiContact="{!newAssessment}" >
                                        </c:EVT_MultipleContactForJobComponents>
                                    </apex:panelGroup>
                                </div>
 <div class="avTableRow">
```